# what is bootstrap capacitor in this circuit how does it improve linearity and how does divide the collector resisitance?

Tags: bjt

[image]

what is bootstrap capacitor in this circuit how does it improve linearity and how does divide the collector resisitance?

Comment: The first circuit is using negative feedback to linearize the system output after what is otherwise a highly non-linear first stage. The second stage is using the follower output, via a cap that moves with it to cause a near-constant voltage across the lower of the two collector resistors for Q1, leading to what amounts to a "stiffened" collector load (the lower resistor now acting more like a current source.)

Comment: i didn't understand it exactly can u explain more

Comment: It sounds like you need to have a talk with the instructor to clear this up, or try to ask a very specific question rather than "what is this and how does it work".

Comment: Perhaps. I'd like you to explain the context of these two circuits, better, though. For example, I think I can discuss the first one more easily (linearization question.) But the 2nd one I cannot put into that context so easily. Besides, it is more incomplete, too.

Comment: could u tell me how can i calculate the value of capacitor and the collector resistors please